# How can I project a matrix on the set of symmetric positive definite matrices with trace 1?

Tags: matrices, optimization, numerical-methods

Given a square matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, I need to compute
$$ \min_{X \in \Omega} \lVert A - X\rVert^2$$
where $\Omega = \{X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} |\, {\rm tr}(X) = 1, X \text{ is symmetric, }X \geq 0 \}$,
namely I want the projection of a given matrix on the set $\Omega$.

But I also neec to compute it fast. I tried using cvx_solver but it's way too slow computing it directly. is there a better way to write this problem? Or is there a known closed formula or quick algorithm for finding such projection?

Comment: Which norm are you using?

Comment: For the solver I tried using norm 2 and Frobenius norm. But both take a bit long

Answer (score 3):

Using Lagrange multipliers for the conditions $X-X^T=0$ and ${\rm tr}(X)=1$ and for the objective function the Frobenius norm, you get the Lagrange functional
$$
L(X,U,v)=\frac12\|A-X\|_F^2+{\rm tr}(U^T(X-X^T))+v(1-{\rm tr}(X))
$$
and from the condition $\frac{∂L}{∂X}=0$ the general form
$$
X=A+(U-U^T)+vI
$$
To get trace $1$, you need $1={\rm tr}(A)+n·v$, the condition for $U$ is not that uniquely determined, only $2(U-U^T)=A^T-A$ has to be satisfied -- which is sufficient to uniquely determine $X$. The simple solution for that is $U=A^T$. Thus
$$
X=\frac12(A+A^T)+\frac1n(1-{\rm tr}(A))·I
$$

Comment: Could you explain in detail how you derived $X=A+(U-U^T)+vI$ and $2(U-U^T)=A^T-A$? Thank you!

Comment: Now it is crystal clear!

Comment: I see.
But that doesn't take care of the positive definite part...

Comment: Ok, for that you need something like the polar decomposition, either per SVD or per the dedicated iteration.. However, I do not see how that meshes with the trace condition. First projecting on a superset of the final set need not be the same as direct projection. Where here the superset it the set of sym.pos.def. matrices, and the subset those that have trace 1.